# Is 'to lift up the stone' an idiom?

Tags: meaning

I was reading Dylan Thomas's letter today and came across the following fragment:

> I had actually very little myself to do with the editing, though Keidrych goes up to Cambridge next year I shall probably - and with you as colleague, or whatever it is, if you'd be - take it all over. And no more Nigel Heseltine when we do: **he can crawl back into the woodwork, or lift up his stone again**. [...]
>
> (From a [letter to Vernon Watkins](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=LXjhAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT447&lpg=PT447&dq=%22I+had+actually+very+little+myself+to+do+with+the+editing%22&source=bl&ots=G4Ms2yQeCO&sig=ACfU3U3VUn-tCRL-0KC5N8U7HhvHhaF39w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwioteDqw433AhUUyzgGHbZXDh8Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22I%20had%20actually%20very%20little%20myself%20to%20do%20with%20the%20editing%22&f=false) dated 15th July, 1937)

If I understand correctly, 'to crawl back into the woodwork' means 'disappear,' but what about the last expression? If 'to lift up the stone' is not an idiom, then the meaning of the whole phrase is unclear to me. Why do you need to go away to lift up a stone?

Comment: This doesn't seem a specific idiom, but I would guess it relates to the idea of an insect living under a stone, and the stone is being lifted so he can crawl back under it. The notion of something crawling out from under a stone or living under a rock is a very common metaphor, even if I can't find a good reference for it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an idiom but is a reference to a well-known insult: **Get/go back under your/his/a, etc., stone** is quite common, see [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=back%20under%20your%20stone&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cback%20under%20your%20stone%3B%2Cc0).

Here's a few examples:

> The Scythians. Feast at Sunsetbooks. Mikhail Akhmanov · 2018
>
> *"Get this, podlot," Kirill said, stepping forward and spreading his shoulders. "I don't sell hash from stinking swamps and you can crawl back under your stone.*

> From Benefits to Billions - Page 192 Mark Bashford · 2019
>
> *"Now take your trolley and get out and crawl back under your stone!”*

> Till the Dust Settles Pat Young · 2017
>
> T*hat’s why he’d got Ray to find him a low-grade nobody of a private eye. Somebody who’d disappear back under a stone after a couple of days’ reconnaissance of Charlotte’s building.*

In "**or lift up his stone again**", the reference is to a slimy, crawling thing that lives under a stone, and that he is lifting it up again so as to return to his home.

Comment: Thanks -- that's really good explanation!